# JAVAXMAIL: Unique ID From messages

Tags: android, email, exception, jakarta-mail, imap

I need a UID from the message so that i can save it to DB and use it further.So here what i am doing:

```
 // Get UniqueID


        List<MailInformation> mailInformation = new ArrayList();
        Folder folder = (Folder) store.getFolder("Inbox");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message [] messageArray = folder.getMessage
        for(Javax.mail.Message message = Arrays.asList(messageArray)){
            UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder) folder;
            Long messageId = uf.getUID(message);
         }
```

But I am getting the following error message:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Message does not belong to this folder

can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong or how to fetch the UID for message.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Message [] messageArray = folder.getMessage`.  This is not valid code.  Please provide a working code segment of what you are doing.  You should probably cast to UIDFolder right away, rather than later.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply, I will update the code and also will try to cast UIDFolder as you suggested.

Comment: Hi @Max i have updated the code. Let me know in case of any thing else.

Comment: You still haven't called getMessage().  I mean, do UIDFolder folder = (UIDFolder) store.getFolder("Inbox")